# Uninstall pre installed java library from the databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

There are some pre installed java libraries in azure databricks https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/6.6.html#installed-java-and-scala-libraries-scala-211-cluster-version

Is there a way to uninstall such libraries?

I have a library conflict. I need to use another version of the spring-core library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databricks includes a number of default Java and Scala libraries. You can replace any of these libraries with another version by using a cluster-scoped init script to remove the default library jar and then install the version you require.

> **Important Note:** Removing default libraries and installing new versions may cause instability or completely break your Databricks cluster. You should thoroughly test any new library version in your environment before running production jobs.

**Refer:** [Databricks - Replace a default library jar](https://kb.databricks.com/libraries/replace-default-jar-new-jar.html).